# В Intellij IDEA maven-проект не видит пакеты JavaFX

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, maven

Создаю с нуля проект maven в IDEA, при попытке запустить класс Main возникают ошибки:

```
Error:(3, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(4, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
Error:(5, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(6, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(7, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
Error:(9, 27) java: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Application
Error:(12, 23) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Stage
location: class sample.Main
Error:(11, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(13, 9) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Parent
location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 39) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getClass()
location: class sample.Main
Error:(13, 23) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
location: class sample.Main
Error:(15, 35) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Scene
location: class sample.Main
Error:(21, 9) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method launch(java.lang.String[])
location: class sample.Main
```

Класс **Main.java**:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>home</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenjavafx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Пробовал на готовом JavaFX проекте - также появляется ошибка из-за пакетов. Версия JDK - 10. Пробовал подключать через dependencies, тоже не помогло.
С чем может быть связано?

Comment: нужно подключить зависимость `javafx`, не плагин

Comment: Попробовал добавить эту dependencies 
из репозитория - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.swarm/javafx/2018.5.0. Нет эффекта.